# Two formula in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a 'daily hire' item in `F5` at $10. When it's

- on hire `(H5=1)` it needs to be paid at 100% (i.e. $10)
- *not* on hire `(H5=0)` it must be discounted by 25%

What is the formula for this?

When I place them in single cells it works:

```
=IF(H5=1,F5*100%) answer is 10<br />
```

and

```
=IF(H5=0,F5*75%) answer is 7.5
```

How do I get both calculations into one cell?

Answer (score 4):

You can nest formulas:

You're not saying what should be in the cell if neither 1 or 0 applies, so I'm assuming blank:

```
=IF(H5=1,F5,IF(H5=0,F5*75%,""))
```

If you know either 1 or 0 will always be filled in

```
=IF(H5=1,F5,F5*75%)
```

Note that I have left out the `*100%'.

Comment: +1 Indeed. There's an extra closing bracket on the second formula though =P

Comment: For clarity, the Excel IF syntax is this:
    =IF(Logical_test, Value_if_true, Value_if_false)
I highly recommend using the "Insert Function" wizard (fx button left of the input box) to get started with formulas.